# Is there any API to add ads to my desktop app

Tags: desktop, embed, ads

I am looking for a way to embed ads to my desktop APIs. There are planty solutions out there for web sites which stream ads from Ad Networks. However, I didn't find one which will allow to get a similar ad content to the app.
Does any one have any experience with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: yuck, why would you want to create adware?

Comment: @lothar ... my guess is for the money (though I hear advertising revenue isn't what it used to be).

Comment: Believe it or not, we want to build an AdWare that people will want to install and use. Hard to believe, ah?

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you targeting?  If you are on Windows you could always display the ads within an embedded/automated IE window (assuming IE is installed).  Alternatively, you could hook up to something like shareasale.com datafeeds and embed the appropriate links in your app.  Clicking on the link (or description, image, etc) would merely cause a browser to launch at the appropriate site.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same pro, I found it was hard to find an ad network focus on desktop apps. Several months ago one of my developer friend told me he is using DesktopAd's ads in his Windows desktop apps. I downloaded their ads SDK and added into my Windows 8.1 apps, it only took me half a day finishing all the works. After that I can get revenue from ad clicks everyday. I hope my answer could be of some help to you.

Comment: Could you please give us a link, what is DesktopAd?